# How In PhpStorm 2019.2.5 to move to alpinejs method definition?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2019.2.5 working with Laravel 8 /  tailwindcss 2 / Alpinejs 2.8 app  project
I wonder if there is a way clicking on Js method in blade.php file to go to this method?
Like cliking on filterPermissionClicked to move to its declarations in the component below.

```
<div class="admin_page_container">
    
    <div class="editor_form_wrapper" x-data="adminUsersAccessComponentSetup()">        
        <select id="filter_permission" name="filter_permission" class="editor_form_input" @click="filterPermissionClicked()" >
            @foreach($permissionsArray as $key=>$value)
                <option value="{{ $key }}" >{{ $key }}->{{ $value }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


@section('scripts')
    
    <script>

        function adminUsersAccessComponentSetup() {
            backendInit('editor', 'users-access')

            return {
                adding: false,
                // /app/View/Components/Admin/UsersAccess.php
                filterPermissionClicked: function () {
                    let filter_permission = document.querySelector("#filter_permission").value

                    console.log('filterPermissionClicked filter_permission::')
                    console.log(filter_permission)
                        ...
                }, // getEditorTitle: function (component) {
            }
        } // function adminUsersAccessComponentSetup() {
    
    </script>

@endsection
```

In Settings/Plugins I found and installed Tailwind Formatter plugin and did not find any
alpinejs plugins...

Are there something?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Alpine.js Support plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15251-alpine-js-support), but you need to upgrade your PhpStorm version in order to use it - its version constraint is 2019.3 and newer.